# Error: AnchorError caused by account: owner. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-lang

Hi I got a project written by a team of devs that left the project, and I successfully ran it locally (on my computer) and I changed it to use **devnet**.
I'm getting this error:
**Error: AnchorError caused by account: owner. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.**

When it's running the following command, then it will fail with the above message:

```
await program.rpc.new(
        (tokenPrice * Number(`1e${tokenInfo.value.decimals}`)) / 1000000,
        mintAddress,
        sportClubPercent,
        ownerPercent,
        minPrizePool,
        {
          accounts: {
            systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
            user: this.wallet.publicKey,
            sportClubAccount: sportClubAddress,
            games: gameAddress.publicKey,
            jackpotAccount: !!splAccount.value[0]
              ? splAccount.value[0]?.pubkey
              : jackpot.publicKey,
            owner: ownerAddress,
          },
          signers: [gameAddress],
          options: this.optionsConfig(slot),
        },
      );
```

I logged the variables as follows:

```
(tokenPrice * Number(`1e${tokenInfo.value.decimals}`)) / 1000000 = 2000
{
    "tokenPrice": 2,
    
    "tokenInfo.value.decimals": 9,
    "mintAddress": "HHZsnr3kspMkoBzXusN3EbgoPL7YwSgNgaiUSg6QZdks",
    "sportClubPercent": "0.4",
    "ownerPercent": "0.6",
    "minPrizePool": "4",
    
    "accounts": {
        "games": "BkJchhHAQ36KnCzNCWohZ7dcyLrhPsn9mHZiiSKPHe84",
        "user": "7ZnJs1GKLCgLX2o54HzPqfPTWnncfHGeX6kcvD47BZLM",
        "jackpotAccount": "Dn4GgpMTiyw1E8yxaMSmt1wAHeK6yfjfy9gn9gRNuNdp",
        "owner": "7ZnJs1GKLCgLX2o54HzPqfPTWnncfHGeX6kcvD47BZLM",
        "sportClubAccount": "6F7D9EVt1UDzoMKqP4Bxut1ke927JDzQqNv5z8dm9GsX",
        "systemProgram": "11111111111111111111111111111111"
    }
}
```

7ZnJs1GKLCgLX2o54HzPqfPTWnncfHGeX6kcvD47BZLM is the owner of the token address HHZsnr3kspMkoBzXusN3EbgoPL7YwSgNgaiUSg6QZdks

Program address is (devnet): 8g4k52qaEC34Nev4b6QsPAnU5JEdkfTmAypgCpecDiLK

in the Rust side:

```
#[program]
pub mod contracts {
...

pub fn new(ctx: Context<InitializeGame>, enter_amount: f64, token_account: Pubkey, sport_club_percent: f64, owner_percent: f64, min_jackpot: f64) -> anchor_lang::Result<()> {
    let new_game_account = &mut ctx.accounts.games;
    new_game_account.enter_amount = enter_amount;
    new_game_account.owner = ctx.accounts.owner.key();
    new_game_account.token_account = token_account;
    new_game_account.jackpot_account = ctx.accounts.jackpot_account.key(); 
    new_game_account.sport_club_account = ctx.accounts.sport_club_account.key(); 
    new_game_account.prize_pool = 0.0;
    new_game_account.is_active = true;
    new_game_account.sport_club_percentage = sport_club_percent;
    new_game_account.owner_percentage = owner_percent;
    new_game_account.min_prize_pool = min_jackpot;
    Ok(())
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeGame<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 32+32+32+1+32+8+8+24+8+8+8)]
    pub games: Account<'info, GameSpl>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub jackpot_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub sport_club_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I've had is, I was not use the token account for the 'owner' and 'sportClubAccount', but I was using the account address.

The solution is to use token account address instead of account address as it's mentioned in the #[derive(Accounts)] in rust.
Also jackpotAccount is a token account address.